# My screen dims then times out on mobile when using A-Frame, NoSleep.js not working

Tags: javascript, aframe

I've tested the demo page for NoSleep.js on my phone and it works just fine, and it seems like an attempt was made to include NoSleep into A-Frame, but it hasn't been working on my apps. Looking for solutions to get it working either within A-Frame's normal build or independently included in my page.

https://richtr.github.io/NoSleep.js/example.html